# How to place an image to the left and right corner of the title in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a dashboard. I need to place the logo at the either side of the title. The expected output is:

[image]

But the output which I am getting is

[image]

The code used is as follows:

**Ui.r**

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(3, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "favicon.png")),
        column(9, "DDIM Use case Dashboard"), 
        column(2, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "favicon.png"))
      )

  )

)
)
```

**Server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(3, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/32px-R_logo.svg.png")),
        column(8, "DDIM Use case Dashboard"), 
        column(1, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/32px-R_logo.svg.png"))
      )

    )

  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

which would give you an output that looks like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!

**[EDIT]**:
With a little css as shown below you can get amazing outputs:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
tags$head(tags$style(".header{background-color:black}
                     #title{
                         color: white;
                        text-align: center;
                     } ")),
  tags$div(class="header",
           titlePanel(
             fluidRow(
               column(3, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/32px-R_logo.svg.png")),
               column(6,   tags$div(id="title","DDIM Use case Dashboard")), 
               column(2),
               column(1, img(height = 50, width = 30, src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/R_logo.svg/32px-R_logo.svg.png"))
             )

           )
      )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The output you get is:
[image: ts]

Comment: Can we center the content? Also is it possible to give the color to the fluidRow()?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar, we could do that using css

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar, I have edited answer to show how you can customize using css. Hope it helps!